# SQL query to linq in mvc

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am creating a report in which i am creating a stored procedure , in that for one particular column I need to use following query

```
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM [dbo].EmployeeDependent WITH (NOLOCK) 
 WHERE [dbo].EmployeeDependent.GCPDocumentId = gdh.GCPDocumentId ) 
     AS [No of Dependants travelling with employee] FROM tablename
```

and this whole subquery is used in the select clause of sql query.
Now I want to convert this query to linq , but somehow i am not able to make it.

Thanks

Comment: `EmployeeDependent.GCPDocumentId = + gdh.GCPDocumentId` what does this line mean?

Comment: Sorry that query is   ,(SELECT COUNT(1)
    FROM [dbo].EmployeeDependent WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE [dbo].EmployeeDependent.GCPDocumentId =  gdh.GCPDocumentId
    ) AS [No of Dependants travelling with employee]
FROM tablename

Comment: Basically you want result of select query in `[No of Dependants travelling with employee]` am i rit?

Comment: I recommend post your whole query

Comment: Try using this query: `EmployeeDependent.Where(x => x.GCPDocumentId == gdh.GCPDocumentId).Count();` If this is a subquery, you need to include the value into parent query.

Answer (score 1):

for the no lock you need to do the following:

```
using (var txn = new TransactionScope(
    TransactionScopeOption.Required, 
    new TransactionOptions
    {
        IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted
    }
))
{

}
```

*note:* *you are creating a new TransactionScope object and telling it to use a read-uncommitted isolation level. The query within the "using" statement now acts as if all its tables were reading with the NOLOCK hint.*

**your query will look like**:

```
using (var txn = new TransactionScope(
    TransactionScopeOption.Required, 
    new TransactionOptions
    {
        IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted
    }
))
{
    var count = from c in EmployeeDependent where c.GCPDocumentId = GCPDocumentId
    select new (DependantsTravelling = c.Count())
}
```